# How to Initialize a Hashtable

Tags: java

How can I initialize the following hashtable?

```
public static Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, String>> tab = new Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, String>>();    
static {
    tab.put("Key1", ????);
    tab.put("Key2", ????);
    tab.put("Key3", ????);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Hashtable`, use the `Map` interface and then a `HashMap` - probably. Unless you need `synchronization` - even then `Hashtable` is pretty useless.

Comment: @BoristheSpider why is that?

Comment: Because `Hashtable` was a legacy collection and all method calls are `synchronized` which makes it **slow**. Further, because the synchronization is internalised it's (almost) entirely useless. Directly from the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) _Unlike the new collection implementations, Hashtable is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `HashMap` in place of `Hashtable`_.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, String>> tab = new Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, String>>();    
static {
    tab.put("Key1", new HashTable<String,String>());
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use, for example, empty `Hashtable`s:

```
public static Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, String>> tab = 
    new Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, String>>();    
static {
    tab.put("Key1", new Hashtable<String, String>());
    tab.put("Key2", new Hashtable<String, String>());
    tab.put("Key3", new Hashtable<String, String>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static {
    Hashtable<String, String> ob = new Hashtable<String, String>;
    ob.put("a","a");
     .. Put key/value...
    tab.put("Key1",ob);  
}
```